OAuth_Approval_Error_Generic just 1st time
My team is using React native on the Android Mobile SDK.
Every time the user selected a server, this OAuth error appeared and they were not allowed to log in at any time; after some modifications to the Android manifest, it was resolved,
BUT now randomly, just when a new apk is reinstalled on different devices (after some downtime from the previous version) we sometimes still get the OAuth_Approval_Error_Generic: An unexpected error occurred during authentication.Try again.
This is resolved only by closing the application and reopening it and it does not appear again.
We use SSO
The process usually is

Uninstall version 1
Spend downtime
Install version 2

Of 10 users, only 4 had the error
Why does it only happen on these 4 devices? Is it a Salesforce thing? Any ideas on how to solve it and it doesn't happen on any device?
Thank you
